# Merge arrays inside of arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have this array:

```
a = [[1,2,3,4,5],[3,5,6,8,12,45],[3,2,1,5,7,9,10,11],[3,5,6,8,2,1,3,4,6]]
```

I want to merge its inner arrays so that they become:

```
a = [[1,2,3,4,5,3,5,6,8,12,45],[3,2,1,5,7,9,10,11,3,5,6,8,2,1,3,4,6]]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do

```
 a = [
     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     [3, 5, 6, 8, 12, 45],
     [3, 2, 1, 5, 7, 9, 10, 11],
     [3, 5, 6, 8, 2, 1, 3, 4, 6]
 ]

a.each_slice(2).map(&:flatten)

# => [
#     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 5, 6, 8, 12, 45],
#     [3, 2, 1, 5, 7, 9, 10, 11, 3, 5, 6, 8, 2, 1, 3, 4, 6]
# ]
```

Read the method [`each_slice(n)`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_slice)

> Iterates the given block for each slice of `n` elements. If no block is given, returns an enumerator.